# How to make sure that the text in TextBox in an excel is found when searched using CNTRL+F?

Tags: microsoft-excel, drawing, microsoft-excel-2003

i have  made a flow chart diagram in an excel sheet using TextBox tool from drawing toolbar.
i've made entries into the text boxes.(No other data is present in the cells of the worksheet)

But now when i search for a particular text in the sheet, it is not showing up. im unable to locate the text using CNTRL+F option, and im forced to go through each TextBox manually for the required text.

One way i have is that, instead of using TextBoxes I can directly enter the text into the cells, but doing this will restrict my requirement(as i have used the cell's width as interval and the TextBox width as the time for which the task will happen).

Is there any way to make sure that the text in the TextBox can be identified when searched using CNTRL+F option or is there any other way to draw a flow chart so that the text can be found when searched.

Help me out in sorting this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got a clue...
I've gave a keyword(that will distinguish the TextBox in interest from others) of the text in the TextBox in a cell and made the cell as hyperlink to the nearest cell where the TextBox with the related text is present.

So, when i search for a text(keyword) using CNTRL+F then this takes me to the cell(in which the keyword is present) and when i click the cell(hyperlink).. it takes me to the cell nearest to the related TextBox.
..Hope this works fine if the TextBoxes have a unique word(s) to distinguish them from one another.

Comment: Would invite other thoughts which would work better...

Answer (score -1):

Your solution would require to update whatever change you make in two places, the text box and the secondary cell. But because Text boxes can be linked to a cell, you can place the content in a cell just behind your textbox, and tell it to show the content of the cell (by using a formula).

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/957-excel-link-textbox-to-cell.html#a1

so when your search brings you to the cell with the content, your appropriately positioned text box will be just on top.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Links can become invalid if the linked page changes.